# Create a new column based on existing columns inside a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Say I have this table `t`:

```
  id value
1  1    10
2  2     3
3  1    55
4  1    20
5  2    98
```

When drawing from `t` I want to add a column `value2` that equals `value` when `id == 2`, otherwise 0

I tried

```
select id, value, max(case when id = 2 then value else 0) from t
```

but it did not work

Comment: You need to show your desired results, because its not clear why you would use `max`?

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression*, not a *statement*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you included a `max` in your attempt but based on your description, this is all you should need.

```
select id, value, case when id = 2 then value else 0 end as value2
from t;
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want a conditional window aggregate:

```
select
  id,
  value,
  max(case when id = 2 then value end) over ()
from t;
```